# Any error found in R responds with Error in app$vspace(new_style$`margin-top` %||% 0) : attempt to apply non-function

Tags: r, tidyverse

I honestly don't know how to make this reproducible. Any error that occurs in R, using tidyverse throws:

```
Error in app$vspace(new_style$`margin-top` %||% 0) : 
  attempt to apply non-function
```

Has anybody else seen this?

Edit:
Here is the sessionInfo() output:

```
R version 4.0.4 (2021-02-15)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18363)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                           
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] rstatix_0.7.0   plotly_4.10.0   ggpubr_0.4.0    forcats_0.5.1   stringr_1.4.0   dplyr_1.0.4     purrr_0.3.4     readr_2.1.2     tidyr_1.2.0     tibble_3.0.6   
[11] ggplot2_3.3.5   tidyverse_1.3.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.8.3      lubridate_1.7.10  assertthat_0.2.1  digest_0.6.29     utf8_1.1.4        R6_2.5.1          cellranger_1.1.0  backports_1.2.1   reprex_2.0.1     
[10] evaluate_0.15     httr_1.4.2        pillar_1.7.0      rlang_1.0.2       lazyeval_0.2.2    readxl_1.3.1      rstudioapi_0.13   data.table_1.14.2 car_3.0-12       
[19] rmarkdown_2.13    labeling_0.4.2    htmlwidgets_1.5.4 munsell_0.5.0     broom_0.7.12      xfun_0.30         compiler_4.0.4    modelr_0.1.8      pkgconfig_2.0.3  
[28] htmltools_0.5.2   tidyselect_1.1.2  fansi_0.4.2       viridisLite_0.4.0 crayon_1.5.1      tzdb_0.3.0        dbplyr_2.1.1      withr_2.5.0       grid_4.0.4       
[37] jsonlite_1.7.2    gtable_0.3.0      lifecycle_1.0.1   DBI_1.1.2         magrittr_2.0.1    scales_1.1.1      cli_3.2.0         stringi_1.5.3     carData_3.0-5    
[46] farver_2.1.0      ggsignif_0.6.3    fs_1.5.0          xml2_1.3.2        ellipsis_0.3.2    generics_0.1.2    vctrs_0.4.0       tools_4.0.4       glue_1.4.2       
[55] hms_1.1.1         yaml_2.3.5        abind_1.4-5       fastmap_1.1.0     colorspace_2.0-0  rvest_1.0.2       knitr_1.38        haven_2.3.1
```

Comment: Same as this? https://github.com/tidyverse/readr/issues/1371

Comment: Please paste the output of `sessionInfo()` to your question.

Comment: I re-installed readr and cli so I don't think it is the same issue as that in the post.

Comment: I'm also getting the same error when trying to build/check a package. Not sure whether it's related but I recently updated Rtools from 3.5 to 4.0

Comment: same error, update the package to latest cran release sorted it!

Comment: I got the error using readr::read_csv2. The solution that worked for me was as mentioned in readr issue 1371, in link given above by user438383, to reintall the cli package (install.packages("cli")). This even if the problem appears using the readr package.

Comment: @MRF have reinstalling any of the things listed above worked for you?