# Get minimum, maximum, average value within a specific group using r

Tags: r, dataframe, datetime, group-by, mutate

I'm using R and I have data as follow:

```
 data<-data.frame(time=c(20230301000000,20230301000010, 20230301000020, 20230301000030,20230301000040,
                        20230301000050, 20230301000100 , 20230301000110 , 20230301000120, 20230301000130,
                        20230301000140, 20230301000150, 20230301000200, 20230301000210, 20230301000220,
                        20230301000230, 20230301000240, 20230301000250,20230301000300),
                 switch=c(40,41,42,43,0,0,0,51,52,53,0,0,0,55,56,57,52,0,0),
                 NH4=c(2,2,3,3,3,5,4,9,9,9,10,11,12,4,4,5,5,7,8))
```

Here, if `switch` >0 , then it means that the switch is on. Otherwise, if `switch` =0, then it means that the switch is off. `switch` always has nonnegative values. I want to calulate the time duration of on and off of `switch` in seconds. `time` is written in year, month, day, hour, minute, second order.  Within each on/ off time duration, I want to calculate the minimum, averge , and maximum value of `NH4`. For the switch on case, I will denote it as `on_NH4_min`, `on_NH4_avg`, and `on_NH4_max`. For the switch off case, I will denote it as `off_NH4_min`, `off_NH4_avg`, `off_NH4_max`. So my desired output should looks like this:

```
summary_data <-data.frame(on_NH4_min=c(2,9,4),
                          on_NH4_avg=c(2.5,9,4,5),
                          on_NH4_max=c(3,9,5),
                          off_NH4_min=c(3,10,7),
                          off_NH4_avg=c(4,11,7,5),
                          off_NH4_max=c(5,12,8),
                          on_time=c(30,20,30),
                          off_time=c(20,20,10))
```

Chat GPT gave me an answer, but it didn't work for me.
Here is the code from Chat GPT.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# Create a variable that indicates whether the switch is on or off
data <- data %>% 
  mutate(switch_on = ifelse(switch > 0, 1, 0))

# Calculate the time duration of each on/off interval
data <- data %>% 
  mutate(interval = cumsum(switch_on != lag(switch_on, default = 0))) %>% 
  group_by(interval, switch_on) %>% 
  mutate(start_time = first(time),
         end_time = last(time),
         duration = difftime(end_time, start_time, units = "secs")) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-interval)

# Calculate the NH4 statistics for each on/off interval
summary_data <- data %>% 
  group_by(switch_on) %>% 
  summarise(NH4_min = min(NH4),
            NH4_avg = mean(NH4),
            NH4_max = max(NH4),
            time = sum(duration)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = switch_on,
              values_from = c(NH4_min, NH4_avg, NH4_max, time),
              names_prefix = c("on_", "off_"))
```

I want to get `summary_data`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using dplyr and tidyr:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data %>%
  group_by(r = consecutive_id(switch > 0)) %>%
  summarize(
    switch = if_else(switch[1] > 0, "on", "off"), 
    time = diff(range(time)), 
    across(NH4, list(min = ~ min(.), avg = ~ max(.), max = ~ max(.)))
  ) %>%
  mutate(grp = cumsum(switch == "on")) %>%
  select(-r) %>%
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = grp, names_from = switch, 
    values_from = c(time, NH4_min, NH4_avg, NH4_max), 
    names_glue = "{switch}_{.value}") %>%
  select(-grp)
# # A tibble: 3 × 8
#   on_time off_time on_NH4_min off_NH4_min on_NH4_avg off_NH4_avg on_NH4_max off_NH4_max
#     <dbl>    <dbl>      <dbl>       <dbl>      <dbl>       <dbl>      <dbl>       <dbl>
# 1      30       60          2           3          3           5          3           5
# 2      20       60          9          10          9          12          9          12
# 3      30       50          4           7          5           8          5           8
```

In using `across(NH4, ..)`, if your real data has more than just ammonium (I'm inferring) and you want to summarize them too, you can just add them, as in `across(c(NH4, CO2), ..)`.

Comment: I tried your code, but it gave me  an error like this:                                                                                               ```Error in app$vspace(new_style$`margin-top` %||% 0) : 
  attempt to apply non-function```   I think I installed the packages, but I don't know why.

Comment: I'm using R-4.2.3, with `dplyr_1.1.0` and `tidyr_1.3.0`. Try reinstalling `cli` (ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71857631/any-error-found-in-r-responds-with-error-in-appvspacenew-stylemargin-top#comment128503605_71857631, you may need to restart R before updating `cli`), but that error has little to do with the code above.

Comment: For clarity, try adding `%>% as.data.frame()` after the `select(-grp)`. If that makes the error vanish, it confirms (to me) that it has nothing to do with this code.

Comment: I tried that, but still get a same error message. MAybe I have the problem from the packages.

Comment: I reinstalled the `cli` package, then and tried your code again. It gave this error. ```Caused by error in `consecutive_id()```           Maybe it seems like the system in r can't find the function `consecutive_id`

Comment: what version of dplyr do you have? I mis-spoke above, I'm on `dplyr_1.1.1`, and in 1.1.0 the `consecutive_id` function was added. In a pinch, you can either use `data.table::rleid`, or you can fashion your own using `my_rleid <- function(z) { r <- rle(z); rep.int(seq_along(r$lengths), times = r$lengths); }`

Comment: My version for `dplyr` is 1.0.7. I will try to update the version and see if the code works.

Comment: I reinstalled the pakage `dplyr` version 1.1.2 and your code worked for me! Thank you.